# When I change color drawable of an actionBar it's white

Tags: android

I'm using this simple code:

```
ActionBar bar = this.getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xFF99CC00));
```

This code is triggered when a imageView is clicked.

This should change ActionBar's background color to green, but it's being displayed as white (it's removing the color, maybe?)

Do you guys know why is this happening?

However, if I do this on `onCreate` method it's being changed.

(When I start this Activity, I do a check to place a color or an other):

```
if (this.isAccepted == -1){
    //nothing
    } else if (this.isAccepted == 0){
        //vermell
        ActionBar bar = this.getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xFFFF4444));
    } else if (this.isAccepted == 1){
        ActionBar bar = this.getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xFF99CC00));
```

As you can see, the code is exactly the same, but it's not being changed when I run the code after clicking a imageView.

Edit:
**Is it actually possible to edit the action bar on the fly? Or just while launching the app?**

Edit2:

I've tried to onCreate, set the bar as a variable, and trying to access it after, but it's doing exactly the same.

Edit3:

Doing some edits to bump the post. This is so weird. I've checked documentation and it doesn't mention anything like "you can't change twice the background" or something like that.

Maybe do I've to invalidate it? I don't really know... Damn.

Edit4: Trying to bump this... I haven't found an answer yet...

Comment: Find the actionbar,  `ActionBar bar = this.getActionBar();` in onCreate and check making it global.

Comment: @Oam i've just tried, and still happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. As I said at one of my edits, you've to request the actionBar. As we've no method, we can use a workaround:

```
this.bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
this.bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

This is working.

Answer (score 1):

You most certainly can change the ActionBar color programmatically.  I typically do it in the onCreateOptionsMenu method.  It's quite simple:

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.Amethyst)));
```

note: set color names in your project's res/values/colors.xml file